# Preserving existing functionality converting HTML to WordPress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have an html web site that is hosted on a virtual machine. I'm looking to shut down the vm to save some money. I have a Wordpress account that I'd like to move the site to (the site design will be changing so I'm not concerned with the layout). On the HTML site, there is a page that an end-user can select a zip code form a drop down list (hard-coded list). When you select the drop down value and select the "Go" button, it will display a list of affiliates that are available given the selected zip code. The zip-code pages are all hard-code (this is a really old site).

My experience with Wordpress has simply been to create pages and use whatever feature was added by a plugin, I've never lifted the hood to see what makes it tick.

Under Wordpress I'd like to replicate this behavior but not have to create each zip code page (there are about 30 pages so it's not awful) but I don't know where to start. Should I use a plug-in or try to code this using WordPress codex? If plug-in, what are some search terms (I'm stumped on what search terms to use to search)?

Comment: Just because you mentioned wanting to save money, are you using wordpress.com, with a free account? To run custom plugins, which you would need, you need to pay for a Business plan.

Comment: Good point but no it's with siteground.